# Simple connection between an int and QComboBox?

Tags: qt, qcombobox

Somehow I feel really silly to ask this question, but I just spent 2 hours reading this site and other sources of information, and I only find complicated solutions, while I strongly believe there must be a really simple one for my problem.

In TCL/TK for example, I can define a variable and bind it to a combobox in 2 lines of code. Similarly in Qt/C++, I have an int defined in one of my classes, and I want the QCombobox to set that int to the number (index) of the selected element.

Do I really have to delve in the depths of model/view and its classes to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need is a slot somewhere that is connected to the combo box's [`currentItemChanged(int)`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qcombobox.html#currentIndexChanged) signal. The slot can update your `int` variable, or do whatever it likes with the selected index. (Look at QComboBox's other signals, there are alternatives.)

(That's one line for the `connect`, and 1, 2 or 3 lines for the slot depending on how you count that.)

Comment: You can take advantage of automatic connection if you use the `void on_widgetName_signalName(args)` syntax.  This removes the need to `connect` the signal to your slot by yourself, so (if you put the body in line with the function name) you can literally do this in one line.

Comment: Note that the `on_widgetName_signalname` trick only works by default if your UI comes from a `.ui` file. If you're setting up the UI manually, you must `setName()` all the widgets you'll connect to, and you must manually call `QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName(QObject*)` on the widget that has other widgets with interesting signals as children.